# How to derive SurveyMonkey's sample size formula?

Tags: sample-size

SurveyMonkey stated their sample size formula on [this page](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/sample-size-calculator/) as following:

$$ Sample\space Size = \frac{\frac{z^2 \times p(1-p)}{e^2}}{1+(\frac{z^2\times(p(1-p)}{e^2N})} $$

How did they derive such formula?